# Would these be considered duplicates?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, duplicates

[Symbols for symmetric difference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128255/symbols-for-symmetric-difference)

[Vertical spacing between character and \hat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128249/vertical-spacing-between-character-and-hat/128253#128253)

[Adjusting the position of \dot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128301/adjusting-the-position-of-dot)

Should these 3 post be considered duplicates?  To me, they seem to be asking the same question.  If so, maybe the title should have a more general name such as link two minus the hat.

> Vertical spacing between stacked (maybe a better term used here instead of stacked) characters.

Comment: To me it seems that encouraging more general questions is a good idea, but a user may not know enough to see that the question is broader than they think, and there will always be gray areas between the sorts of questions that really are the same, and those that are definitely different.

Comment: Ofcourse I am no better judge or have experience(low rep), adding my view, Observe some Q's how they are made Duplicate by community and follow the pattern.